# Serenity BDD testing for clicking multiple buttons

Tags: windows, netbeans, cmd, automated-tests, serenity-bdd

I have created a Serenity Test. What it does is Open Google then search for `online calculator`. Then it should:

1. Click 1
2. Click +
3. Click 1
4. Click =

My code is :

```
givenThat(gdguradio).wasAbleTo(openTheApplication);
when(gdguradio).attemptsTo(Search.forTheTerm("online calculator"));
when(gdguradio).attemptsTo(EnterInFormula.forEnteringinFormula());
//guradio.AddingTwoNumbers();
guradio.shouldSeeSumEquals("3");
```

Then my `EnterInFormula.forEnteringinFormula()`

```
@Step("{0} clears all the completed items")
    public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actor) {
        actor.attemptsTo(Click.on(SearchBox.NumberOne));
        actor.attemptsTo(Click.on(SearchBox.NumberPlus));
        actor.attemptsTo(Click.on(SearchBox.NumberTwo));
        actor.attemptsTo(Click.on(SearchBox.NumberEquals));
    }
    public static EnterInFormula forEnteringinFormula() {
        return instrumented(EnterInFormula.class);
    }
```

My SearchBox :

```
public class SearchBox {
    public static Target SEARCH_FIELD = Target.the("search field").located(By.name("q"));
    public static Target CalculatorFormula = Target.the("Calculator Formula").located(By.id("cwos"));
    public static Target NumberOne = Target.the("1").located(By.id("cwbt33"));
    public static Target NumberTwo = Target.the("2").located(By.id("cwbt34"));
    public static Target NumberPlus = Target.the("+").located(By.id("cwbt46"));
    public static Target NumberEquals = Target.the("=").located(By.id("cwbt45"));
}
```

It looks OK until the pressing of keys. It only presses number 2 so the test fails.

How to correctly write the clicking of buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine. This looks like a normal Selenium automation issue - Selenium says the element is not enabled, so for Selenium, it probably isn’t. You may need to wait for some event or state before the button becomes ready to click.

Comment: Hi @john kindly check my other OP [link to OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203988/serenity-bdd-dont-delete-browser-memory)