# Serenity BDD dont delete Browser Memory

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd

```
@Managed(uniqueSession = true, clearCookies = Never)
```

I have a serenity app that has a Oauth login mechanism using the Microsoft login.
I am using the above code to make browser retain browser's memory. What I want to happened is I have a test to Login using the Microsoft Oauth. Then Have another test that will open the dashboard. Since the previous test already log in. I am hoping that Opening the dashboard of the app should be pass. Unfortunately when I access the dashboard. The test will ask for login again. Meaning that the previous login was deleted from the browser's memory.

> How to properly retain the browser's memory in Serenity BDD screenplay test using only Google Chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

In this conversation similar issue was discussed - https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/273. If I right understood this feature have to work, but in your case it is not working. What I would do:

1. add issue [here](https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues)
2. ask in the [RocketChat](https://serenity-bdd.rocket.chat/channel/general)

Both of the options are good, because the contributors of Serenity BDD can provide the best help for your issue. Also you can talk there directly with [John Ferguson Smart](https://johnfergusonsmart.com/).

Comment: Will try it as soon as possible.